# DispNet Architecture - Convolutional Layers

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

[DispNet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkfLA.png)

I am trying to understand the DispNet architecture

They are labeling from the third convolution Conv3a and then Conv3b and so on.

I am not able to grasp the reasoning behind it, does it has to with the Stride? they are switching from stride = 2 and stride = 1, between "a" and "b"

I mean why not just label them in order, Conv1 -> Conv2 -> Conv3 -> Conv4

I think I am missing something, could someone give me some light on it?
I would really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the second part of the architecture, you can see the long-range links,coming partially from the ConvXb, those with a stride of 1.

The ConvXa have a stride of 2 to implement the "contractive part" of the DispNet/FlowNet architecture, while the ConvXb are both part of the contractive end expansive part of the architecture and have thus a neutral role on hte tensor sizes (stride 1).

Since there is a symetry between the contractive and expansive part, the conv layers are numbered to correspond to each other. But the contractive part is divided into a/b because only the 'b' part serves as input to the expansive part of the network.